# Alter 'fget1' while loop to pull values from single column file to create two column .csv file, Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, while-loop

I have  large (1000,000+KB) single column .txt files of data from 52 probes at specific time intervals (see below for format).  From reading other posts I have a program to put the data from a single probe into a file (see program below).

Does anyone have advice on how to alter the while loop to include the corresponding time value comma separated from the probe data value (see desired format below)?  I'd like to be able to give co-workers a .txt file they can import into Excel to plot probe data.

```
***how my single column data .txt file is formatted***
59 lines of header information
time 1
probe 1 data
probe 2 data
...50 other probes
time 2     
probe 1 data
probe 2 data
...50 other probes
and so on


% program to put probe 1 data (which repeats every 51 lines) into a file
m = 1;
d = fopen('C:\path.txt');
while ~feof(d)
    for n=1:59
      tline = fgetl(d);
    end
  while ischar(tline)
      tline = fgetl(d);
      Probe1(m).txt = tline;
     m = m+1;
     for n=1:51
      tline = fgetl(d);
     end
  end
end
fclose(d);asdf


***desired format for single probe data .txt file***
time 1, probe 1 data at time 1
time 2, probe 1 data at time 2
and so on...
```

Thank you for your time and any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following code. You need to add to read the time values and store them. Then you can use `dlmwrite` to save the `csv`-file.

```
clc; clear;

num_head = 3;   % number of header lines
num_probes = 3; % number of probes

f = fopen('data.txt','r');

% Ignore header
for i = 1:num_head
    fgetl(f);
end

t_num = 1; % Actual time step

while ~feof(f)
    time(t_num,1) = str2double(fgetl(f));

    for p_num = 1:num_probes % loop through probes
        probe_data(t_num,p_num) = str2double(fgetl(f));
    end

    t_num = t_num+1;
end

fclose(f);

for p_num = 1:num_probes
    dlmwrite(sprintf('data_probes_%d.csv',p_num),[time probe_data(:,p_num)],',');
end
```

Example data file (with 3 header lines and three probes per time point):

```
header1
header2
header3
0.0
4
3
2
0.1
7
6
5
0.2
9
8
7
```

Comment: Your code worked perfectly, thank you.  If I wanted to create .csv files for only a few of the probes I suppose I would alter the p_num statement in the final for loop.

Comment: Exactly. You can use e.g. `for p_num = [1 4 10]` to create the `csv` files for just a few probes (1, 4 and 10 here).